# "FileNotFoundError:[Errno 2] No such file or directory in windows" on constructed path

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, operating-system

My file path is

```
C:/Users/Ratul/Downloads/Machine_Learning_Data/reddit_data/reddit_data/
```

There are many folders in that directory. I need to look through those directories and open files that starts with 'RC_'

[image: As can be seen from the image]

Here's my code:

```
import sqlite3
import json
import os
from datetime import datetime

timeframe = '2015-05'
sql_transaction = []

connection = sqlite3.connect('{}.db'.format(timeframe))
c = connection.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_reply(parent_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, comment_id TEXT UNIQUE, parent TEXT, comment TEXT, subreddit TEXT, unix INT, score INT)")

def format_data(data):
    data = data.replace('\n',' newlinechar ').replace('\r',' newlinechar ').replace('"',"'")
    return data

def find_parent(pid):
    try:
        sql = "SELECT comment FROM parent_reply WHERE comment_id = '{}' LIMIT 1".format(pid)
        c.execute(sql)
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result != None:
            return result[0]
        else: return False
    except Exception as e:
        #print(str(e))
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_table()
    row_counter = 0
    paired_rows = 0

    with open('C:/Users/Ratul/Downloads/Machine_Learning_Data/reddit_data/reddit_data/{}/RC_{}'.format(timeframe.split('-')[0],timeframe), buffering=1000) as f:
        for row in f:
            row_counter += 1
            row = json.loads(row)
            parent_id = row['parent_id']
            body = format_data(row['body'])
            created_utc = row['created_utc']
            score = row['score']
            comment_id = row['name']
            subreddit = row['subreddit']
            parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)
            # maybe check for a child, if child, is our new score superior? If so, replace. If not...

            if score >= 2:
                existing_comment_score = find_existing_score(parent_id)
```

But it seems there is some mistake in the path. I get an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Ratul/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/test02.py",
>   line 36, in 
>       with open('C:/Users/Ratul/Downloads/Machine_Learning_Data/reddit_data/reddit_data/{}/RC_{}'.format(timeframe.split('-')[0],timeframe), buffering=1000) as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory:
>   'C:/Users/Ratul/Downloads/Machine_Learning_Data/reddit_data/reddit_data/2015/RC_2015-05'

I'm not sure what wrong I did there. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and

```
print('C:/Users/Ratul/Downloads/Machine_Learning_Data/reddit_data/reddit_data/{}/RC_{}'.format(
       timeframe.split('-')[0],timeframe))
```

instead of `open`. Check if all exists - because for some of your values *it does not exist*. Hence the error.

If most of your files exist, it is far easier to handle the error itself:

```
myname = 'C:/Users/Ratul/Downloads/Machine_Learning_Data/reddit_data/reddit_data/{}/RC_{}'.format(timeframe.split('-')[0],timeframe)

try:
    with open(myname, buffering=1000) as f:
        for row in f:
            row_counter += 1
            row = json.loads(row)
            parent_id = row['parent_id']
            body = format_data(row['body'])
            created_utc = row['created_utc']
            score = row['score']
            comment_id = row['name']
            subreddit = row['subreddit']
            parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)
            # maybe check for a child, if child, is our new score superior? If so, replace. If not...

            if score >= 2:
                existing_comment_score = find_existing_score(parent_id)
except FileNotFoundError as fnfError:
    print(myname)
    print(fnfError)
```

The `open()` command does not care about you using `\` or `/` - if using `\` you should escape it or use raw strings (aka: `r'C:\some\dir\file.txt'`) - your syntax is ok as is - open() will use the appropriate directory delimiters under windows even if you give it `'c:/somedir/file.txt'`

Readup: [About error handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: I tried your code and it says there is no such file or directory but I have directory there as can be seen from screen shot.

Comment: what exactly is the error message, what is printed as `myname`. What happens if you copy/pase the `myname` content into Explorer and try to navigate to the file there?